# Screen flow for leads with no company field

Tags: leads, screen-flow

I created a Screen flow to capture basic lead information (first name, last name, email).

When I run the Debug, I get this error:

> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Required fields are missing: [Company].

When I edit 'Create Records', what should I match the Company field as this field doesn't exist on my flow? Is there a way to display 'Not provided' on the Lead's Company field in Salesforce once the user submits the flow?

Thank you.

[Edit]

[image]

Comment: Do you want company name to be Not Provided when lead is created from screenflow?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Yes ideally - I need the Company field to be filled in somehow but I don't know how to set it up in the 'Create Reports' under Set Field Values for the Lead.

Comment: Can you share the create records component screenshot so can share the process for it

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - just added the screenshot in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: In the same way how you defined Leadsource and status . In similar way define Company field with Value as 'Not Provided'

Comment: `Lead.Company` is a required field per the schema - it just needs to be non-null when the record is saved (though check to make sure your Duplicate Rules can accommodate a constant value here)

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I did what you suggested and it worked. I can see how simple it is now so thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in the above comments you can default the lead `company` field to "No Information" like you did it for `Status` and `LeadSource` fields in Screen.

As highlighted by @cropredy check to make sure your Duplicate Rules can accommodate a constant value here